# convert string into math expression .net/php Not library but actual logic

Tags: string, math, logic, expression

Provided a string like `"y = 1, x = 2, w = x + y +1"`

How to make .net or any language convert it into a math expression and calculate it?

Now I am more concerned regarding the logic behind it not a framework.
My logic would be the following, but it's still incomplete is there anything faster or better and also help complete the logic if it's ok???

Pseudo-code:

```
symbols[] = { "=","+" ... "-"}
string a = "y = 1, x = 2, w = x +  y +1";
a = a.replace(" ","");
highlevelsplit = a.split("=");

for expr e in highlevelsplit 
{
   if(e.containts(=))
   {
      highlevelsplit[highlevelsplit.indexof(e)] = calc(highlevelsplit[highlevelsplit.indexof(e)+1]
   }     

}

function calc(string expr)
{
     array[] = expr.toCharArray();
     variables[][];
     var c;
     var currentVariable; 

     for int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++
     {
       c = array[i];
       if( symbols.containts(c) )
       {
          if( c.equals("+"))
          {

          }
             ....
       }
       else if ( c.notNumber && variables.containtsKey(c))
       {

       }
       else if ( Float.TryParse(c))
       {

       }
       else //probably a letter?
       {
          variables.push(c,0);
          currentVariable = c;
       }
}
}
```

Comment: So you want to parse it?

Comment: i guess so :P but not not just x = 1 + 2/3, but more like a=1 b=2 3x=5a+2b+2/3 if that makes any dif

Comment: Well, looks like you have to search for how to parse expressions. There's a lot of material out there that can help you.

Comment: `highlevelsplit = a.split("=")` doesn't make sense to me. shouldn't "," have higher precedence than "="?

Comment: Right, user829755. Trim the input string to remove spaces, split it by commas, and assuming the last element in the resultant array is the expression to be evaluated, parse the other elements for variable assignment and build the expression. If this is to be generalized, it will require recursion, but the example suggests that complexity is unnecessary. Also, don't forget to handle the operators according to the order of operations (possibly including parentheses).